# Sync data between two offline devices running the same PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps, offline

I developed a PWA that uses the IndexedDB/Service Workers to allow users to work offline. The problem is that different users working offline need to sync the offline data created. In this case one user depends on what the other have created in offline mode.
Is there a way to share IndexedDB between devices ? Is there another approach to send JSON to another offline device ?

Comment: Did you figured this out?